# C# SqlServer.Types version 10 or higher could not be found for foreach method

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, unit-testing, foreach

I've been having some trouble getting a unit test to run. In the test, I have a method that does the following:

```
foreach(var x in context.Examples)
{
    eList.Add(new Example());
}
```

When I run this method, the "in" in the foreach line throws and error reading "Spatial types and functions are not available for this provider because the assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types' version 10 or higher could not be found."

I looked online and tried fixing the issue by reinstalling Microsoft.SqlServer.Types in the package manager, double checking that it's included in the project's references, and (since this is a unit test application) add the following lines before the foreach loop:

SqlServerTypes.Utilities.LoadNativeAssemblies(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);

```
        SqlProviderServices.SqlServerTypesAssemblyName =
            "Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=14.0.314.76, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91";
```

It still throw the same exception. What's weird is that none of the other instances of a foreach loop throw an exception, only this one. Am I missing something?

Comment: What is the version of SqlServer?

Comment: problem is not unit testing but database. Maybe you have some kind of spacial data, maybe dbgeometry

Comment: It's version 14.0.314.76. I do have a DbGeometry as well, but I believe that's why I installed the sqlserver dll in the first place.

Comment: I said Sql server version. if its 2012- version is 11.*, if 2014- 12.* and so on

Comment: Ah, my mistake. It's version 13.0.1601

Answer (score 1):

try this in *app.config*

> ```
>   <dependentAssembly>
>     <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Types" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" />
>     <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-14.0.0.0" newVersion="14.0.0.0" />
>   </dependentAssembly>
> ```

Comment: I had tried each steps mentioned in the docs as well as others. But strangely this was missing from my file(though it was an existing and working project). Adding this cleared the mess. Although I kept oldVersion to`"0.0.0.0-10.0.0.0"` only. Glad that it worked. Thanks man!!!